# KendoGrid - display datasource as rows (not columns)

Tags: kendo-grid, datasource, rows

There is a way to display the dataSource as rows and not columns?

My dataSource has only one record with 30 properties. I would like to display the properties as rows (property1 => row1, property2 => row2, ...) instead of columns (property1 => column1, property2 => column2, ....).

In fact, I would like to retrieve 3 records (each one with 30 properties), but the 3 records would be the colums and the common 30 properties would be the rows.

How can I do that?

This is what I did so far, but I'm not sure this is the right way.

```
var _dataSource = function () {

        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: { // returns only 3 records
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema : {
                data: "data",
                total: "total",
                parse: function (data) {

                    console.log(data);
                    var dataArray = [];
                    var i = 0;
                    for (var property in data[0]) {

                        console.log(property);
                        console.log(data[0][property]);

                        var record = {
                            header: "",
                            headerId: "",
                            record1: "",
                            record2: "",
                            record3: ""
                        };

                        record.header = headerRows[i]; // array of header string (the 30 properties)
                        record.headerId = property;
                        record.record1 = data[0][property];
                        record.record2 = data[1][property];
                        record.record3 = data[2][property];

                        console.log(record);


                        dataArray.push(record);
                        i++;
                    }
                    return dataArray;
                }
            }
        });

        return dataSource;
    };
```

But this gives the error: `TypeError: e is undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! So simple!

Instead of build the logic on `schema.parse`, I did it on `schema.data`.

Actually, it makes more sense on `schema.data`. Don't know why I was trying on `schema.parse`.